# Waiting for a process idiom

Tags: python, python-3.x, queue, multiprocessing

Is there a better way to write the following idiom:

```
while q.empty():      # wait until data arrives.
    time.sleep(5)  
while not q.empty():  # start consuming data until there is nothing left.
    data = q.get()    # this removes an item from the queue (works like `.pop()`)
    # do stuff with data
```

`q` is an instance of `multiprocessing.Queue()` in case that is relevant although I think the above construct can be found elsewhere too.

I feel there has to be a better way to do this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default if you use `.get(..)` you will have a *blocking queue*. Indeed if we look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue.get):

> ```
> get([block[, timeout]])
> ```
>
> Remove and return an item from the queue. If **optional args `block` is `True` (the default)** and `Timeout` is `None` (the default), **block if necessary until an item is available**. If timeout is a positive number, it blocks at most timeout seconds and raises the Queue.Empty exception if no item was available within that time. **Otherwise (`block` is `False`)**, return an item if one is immediately available, else raise the Queue. Empty exception (timeout is ignored in that case).

So you can safely use:

```
while True:
    data = q.get()
    # ... process data
```

So no need to do "*polling*". A simple `.get(..)` will usually sleep until the system notifies that data is available (although this might depend on how for instance the operating system.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. To take it a step further (let me know if this is becoming a second question) assuming the consuming of the queue is faster than the filling, how does one exist the `while`? Do I **need to** `put` a *flag* item that I can check for and `break`?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis: you can add a timeout (e.g. 10 milliseconds) and if by then no content has arrived, it will raise an exception. So you can use the `try`-`except` mechanism to exit the `while` loop in that case.